# Cant show image from ouside root directory server

Tags: php

Here my code :

```
public function show_image(){
    $file = "logout.png";
    $fileDir = '/home/dazor/Pictures/';

    if (file_exists($fileDir . $file))
    {
        $contents = file_get_contents($fileDir . $file);
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileDir . $file));
        echo $contents;
    }
}
```

list of my files :

```
total 136
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dazor dazor 40464 Jul  1  2014 ilkom.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 dazor dazor 54662 Nov 13 19:33 ilkom.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 dazor dazor 20677 Oct 10 01:12 image.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dazor dazor 15305 Oct  5 19:23 logout.png
```

The problem is, the image is not showing and just show, am I doing wrong ??

Comment: What's the full path to the image? `/home/dazor/Pictures/logout.png`? Can you show what `echo getcwd();` shows?

Comment: probably a permission issue, file is owned by dazor, not php

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use symlink on linux

```
ln -s TARGET LINK_NAME
```

**Example** : `ln -s /var/www/app_folder/assets/Pictures /home/dazor/Pictures`

So you can access image on your public folder

Answer (score 0):

make sure no output sent before `header()` in your code.

from the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.